# AWS VPN connection to private network works differently depending on seemingly external factors

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, saml-2.0, aws-vpn

#### context:

AWS VPN to multiple accounts with saml authentication

#### these two cases work fine:

CASE aws vpn client on mac:

- it just works

CASE aws vpn client on fedora linux (copr vorona/aws-rpm-packages) && client machine is connected to generic network:

- it just works

#### this is where the issue is:

CASE aws vpn client on fedora linux (copr vorona/aws-rpm-packages) && client machine is connected to mobile hostspot:

- specifically there are 2 RDS clusters in 2 different aws accounts I am trying to connect to:

  - it always connects to one but does not connect to the other one in this case
  - about the one failing to connect: the DNS query receives a successful response but it seems that the TCP session fails to initialize and it retry sending SYN packets until it times out

#### question:

anybody has any idea whay this might happen?

#### what I would expect to happen:

when on fedora linux I can connect to private resources regardless of which wifi/cabled connection my client machine is  connected to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution in the official [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-user/linux-troubleshooting.html)

> ###### Cause
>
> The client interacts with systemd-resolved, a service available
> on Linux systems, which serves as a central piece of DNS management.
> It is used to configure DNS servers that are pushed from the ClientVPN
> endpoint. The problem occurs because systemd-resolved doesn't set the
> highest priority to DNS servers that are provided by the ClientVPN
> endpoint. Instead, it appends the servers to the existing list of DNS
> servers that are configured on the local system. As a result, the
> original DNS servers might still have the highest priority, and
> therefore be used to resolve DNS queries.
>
> ###### Solution
>
> Add the following directive on the first line of the OpenVPN
> config file, to make sure that all DNS queries are sent to the VPN
> tunnel.
>
> ```
> dhcp-option DOMAIN-ROUTE .
> ```

I find it weird that the behaviour changes depending on which access point i am connected to, but I won't complain ;).
If anybody has an Idea as to why this might happen I am very curious.